# Load several scripts in certain order

Tags: javascript, typescript, onload

I need to load several js scripts in certain order. In fact I'm doing it in typescript, I can't use jQuery, only pure ts/js. What I have now is:

```
var script1 = document.createElement('script');
script1.type = 'text/javascript';
script1.src = 'script1.js';
document.head.appendChild(script1);
script1.onload = function () {

    var script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script2.type = 'text/javascript';
    script2.src = 'script2.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script2);
    script2.onload = function () {

        etc...

    }

}
```

It works, but I believe that there is some more elegant way to do that? Please give examples in vanilla javascript or typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! There is. Use `Promises` and `async/await`

```
function loadScript(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = url
    document.head.appendChild(script)
    script.onload = () => resolve()
  })
}

async function loadScripts() {
  await loadScript('script1.js')
  await loadScript('script2.js')
  // ..
}

loadScripts().then(_ => console.log('All scripts loaded in specified order'))
```

Comment: How do I do that in TypeScript?

Comment: valid javascript is valid typescript @Martin

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you explain how this all works?  I am not familiar with using promises in this fashion.

Comment: `loadScript` returns a Promise which is resolved only when either resolve or reject is called. I'm calling `resolve` on the script load callback. `await` waits for a promise to resolve before proceeding, so it'll wait for the script to load indirectly (because that's when the promise is resolved). Hence mission accomplished @BrandonDixon

Comment: Ah, I see now, in a sense, by using await, in the loadScripts() you are forcing the scripts to load synchronously, but the fact that loadScripts() itself is async still gets the job done in an async fashion.

Comment: Thank you! With your help and little corrections it worked! I've added a `--target es2015` option to `tsc` compiler, and used my `init` function instead of `console.log` and viola! it works and now it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way might be something like the code below, where you define everything first, but still load everything in order as above.  This uses a helper function to append, then set the load function of the next script, and stores the script references in an array to make this streamlined.

```
/*
* Load the scripts in a specific order
*/
function loadScripts() {
    var scripts = [];
    var numScripts = 2
    for (let i=0; i<numScripts, i++) {
        scripts[i] = document.createElement('script');
        scripts[i].type = 'text/javascript';
        scripts[i].src = '"script"+i+".js"; //NOTE: if your scripts start on 1, not 0, you need "i+i"
    }
    loadScriptHelper(scripts,0);
}

/*
* Helper function for load scripts
*/
function loadScriptHelper(scripts,i) {
    document.head.appendChild(scripts[i]);
    scripts[i].onload = function() {
        loadScriptHelper(scripts,i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was thinking of making a function (DRY - don't repeat yourself), but I felt that this `onload` thing is too old, so I wanted some more fresh approach!